# A calendar with two-way sync with Google Calendar

Tags: email, calendar, synchronization, google-calendar

I have my email setup with a host that I have imported in my primary Gmail account using POP. But when I receive calendar events on this email, and I click to RSVP, it takes me to a GCal page and says something along the lines of "This domain is not setup with Google Calendar".

**Is there a way to prevent this?** I know I can use Google Apps but I don't want to migrate everything - all I need is a calendar that:

- Can receive and send invites using my email (from Gmail)
- Can RSVP others' invites
- Can import into Google Calendar (iCal, Webcal)

Is this even possible?